# gdb how to simplify memory address/offset?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

This is my sample c code

```
user@linux:~$ gdb -q hello
Reading symbols from hello...done.
(gdb) 
(gdb) list 
1   #include<stdio.h>
2   
3   int main()
4   {
5       printf("Hello World!\n");
6       return 0;
7   }
8
```

And this is it's assembly code.

```
(gdb) disassemble main 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000000063a <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000000063b <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000000063e <+4>: lea    0x9f(%rip),%rdi        # 0x6e4
   0x0000000000000645 <+11>:    callq  0x510 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000000064a <+16>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000000064f <+21>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000000650 <+22>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

The memory address contains 18 character and most of them is number `0`.

Instead of displaying all numbers, would it be possible to simplify it?

Let say `0x63a` instead of `0x000000000000063a`

Comment: Maybe this could help. http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_9.html#SEC56
n, the repeat count
The repeat count is a decimal integer; the default is 1. It specifies how much memory (counting by units u) to display. Or here possibly : https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Print-Settings.html

Comment: `0x000000000000063a` has 16 hex digits = 8 bytes.  The `0x` are just "decoration" to tell you it's a hex number.

Answer (score 4):

> The memory address contains 18 character and most of them is number 0

There is no "the memory" here. You are apparently talking about *displaying* addresses.

> Let say 0x63a instead of 0x000000000000063a

You are on a 64-bit system, and every address is *exactly* 64-bits. Displaying addresses as something other than a 64-bit number would be very confusing.

P.S. You have a position-independent executable. It doesn't *actually run* at address `0x000000000000063a`. If you use `start` and `disas main`, you will get a very different result.